# update panel not working after adding jquery file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm having trouble with my update panel not working after I have added the jquery file, it runs fine without it but as soon as I put it in it no refreshes the update panel? Any Ideas?

the problem occours when I add the jquery-1.7.2.min.js file.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MLIVRtelephone.aspx.vb" Inherits="MLIVRtelephone" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="OrgChart" Namespace="OrgChart.Core" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


<%@ Register src="Header.ascx" tagname="Header" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            height: 23px;
        }

        #drop {
min-height: 100px;
width: 200px;
border: 3px dashed #ccc;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}
html .RadOrgChart .rocItem {
width: 120px;
}


.middle
{
text-align:center;
}
    </style>


    <uc1:Header ID="Header1" runat="server" />
<head runat="server">
<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
              <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
            </asp:ScriptManager>


<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td width="800px" class="style1">
                         <div id="layout" runat="server">
            <br />
            <telerik:RadOrgChart ID="RadOrgChart1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
                   <ItemTemplate>

           <asp:Button CausesValidation = "false" OnClick="getlayer" runat="server" ID="LinkButtonNode" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text")%>' CssClass="middle"></asp:Button>
       </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:RadOrgChart>
                                        <br />
              </div>
        </td>
        <td align="right" class="style1">
                            <div align="left" id="layer" runat="server">
            </div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" >
            </asp:UpdatePanel></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="800px">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">



        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="800px">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

    </form>
```

Comment: Anything new? Did you solve it?

Comment: Sorry, I left work right after I did my last post. I'm about to start work on it again now.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense, jQuery is a javascript library and only referencing it can't cause anything.

The only option I can think of is that you're using other library that uses the `$` sign like jQuery.

Try change your code to this:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$.noConflict();
```

It's possible that `Telerik RAD controls` that you're using referencing jQuery and you override their reference.

Comment: That is the whole page, I don't get it either. I'm new to jquery so its driving me nuts

Comment: @Imsopov. Ohhh, now I think I know what's the problem. I think Telerik rad controls reference jQuery by them self, so you probably override their reference.

Comment: @Imsopov. Remove your reference and try this `alert($)` if it's not `undefined` then you have other references to jQuery.

Comment: Found this at the bottom of the generated code.. So if I take out my reference jquery should already be added?

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[

    Sys.Application.add_init(function() {

    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadOrgChart, null, null, null, $get("RadOrgChart1"));

    });

    //]]>

    </script>

Comment: @Imsopov I don't know, I don't use asp.net controls, look at telerik website. Did you try the alert thing?